# Do Zachariah 14 and Ezekiel 37 claim that the state of Israel will exist before the arrival of the Messiah?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, tanach, messiah, eretz-yisrael, state-of-israel

I heard someone say that the task of the Messiah will be to establish Israel as a theocratic monarchy. However, this person claimed that Zachariah 14 and Ezekiel 37 claim that Israel will exist beforehand. However, after I read Zachariah 14 and Ezekiel 37, I struggle to connect the two thoughts within the proper context? Can someone explain why this person might be suggesting this?

Comment: "_I struggle to connect the two thoughts within the context_" Why, then, do you bother? "_All these and similar matters_ [regarding the Messianic times] _cannot be definitely known by man until they occur for **these matters are undefined in the prophets' words** and **even the wise men have no established tradition regarding these matters** except their own interpretation of the verses_ ..." ([Mishneh Torah, Kings & Wars, ch. 12](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188357/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-12.htm#v2)).

Answer (score -1):

"Theocracy" means a government that rules in the name of God. The modern day Israeli government does not do that at all. So it is still makes sense for Israel's nation to exist before the Messiah establishes a theocratic monarchy.

Also I am coming from a reformist angle, but prophetic visions and prophetic anticipations are not absolute.

The story in 1 Kings 22:1-23 implies that prophetic visions are not set in stone. Prophetic vision can be completely divorced from actual reality. The book of Daniel in fact says that the apocalypse has already happened, with the kingdom of the Archangel Michael arriving shortly after Antiochus IV's reign during the Greek era.

Comment: risky territory. i’d say that not all negative prophecies have to occur, but God will indeed fulfill His word regarding the positive prophecies. And I would even say that messiah is a person, not some sort of movement, there will be a human king of Israel from the line of David, may it be soon